# How to alter cck field title using hook_form_alter?

Tags: forms

I want to change #weight, #prefix, #title for a cck field.

First I tried the following code.

```
function test_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //Working   
    $form['field_test1']['#weight'] = -5;   
    $form['field_test1']['#prefix'] = 'This text will rule them all!';

    //Not working
    $form['field_test1']['#title'] =  'test title';
    $form['field_test1']['und']['#title'] = 'test title';
    $form['field_test1']['und'][0]['#title'] = 'test title';        
}
```

It is working good with #weight, #prefix elements.

```
//Working   
$form['field_test1']['#weight'] = -5;   
$form['field_test1']['#prefix'] = 'This text will rule them all!';
```

But not working for #title element in anyways.

```
$form['field_test1']['#title'] =  'test title'; //Not working
$form['field_test1']['und']['#title'] = 'test title'; //Not working
$form['field_test1']['und'][0]['#title'] = 'test title'; //Not working
```

I tried with **#after_build** as well but no luck.

```
function test_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'test_after_build';   
}
function test_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
    //Working   
    $form['field_test1']['#weight'] = -5;   
    $form['field_test1']['#prefix'] = 'This text will rule them all!';  

    $form['field_test1']['#title'] =  'test title'; //Not working
    $form['field_test1']['und']['#title'] = 'test title'; //Not working
    $form['field_test1']['und'][0]['#title'] = 'test title'; //Not working  

    return $form;
}
```

Please give me the solution for alter cck field title through form_alter.

*Thanks in advance,
Logan*

Answer (score 0):

First, you may check the exact field array with `dsm()`

```
function MODULE_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dsm($form);
}
```

[image: form taxonomy dsm]

In the result returned by `dsm()`,  *#title* is set in 2 places. So just try :

```
$form['field_bibliographie']['#title']= t('Foo');//doesn't work
$form['field_bibliographie']['und'][0]['#title']= t('Foo');//correct one
```

I see no reason for which it would not take the correct value if you set the exact field array

Comment: In the taxonomy taken as example, I don't know why `#title` is found in 2 places, if somebody wishes to comment/explain that point

Comment: I already used dsm and tried but no luck.